# Python(+pandas) round up if equally spaced

Tags: javascript, python, pandas, rounding

I have an application where the backend uses python with data in a pandas dataframe, and the frontend uses javascript. I am running into an issue where they round differently. Python rounds to the nearest even number if the distance between 2 numbers is equal, while javascript rounds up in that case.
For example, python's `round(0.1250, 2)` returns `0.12`. In javascript there is no "round to n decimals" function, so the workaround often used is `Math.round(0.1250*100)/100` which rounds to `0.13`.
I have tried getting javascript to round like python, but have had no luck, so my question now is, can I force python to round like javascript somehow, specifically on a panda's dataframe, but I think that just uses the builtin `round` function